# Inflate menu from alert dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-menu

I'm trying to inflate a menu from an alterdialog, so when the user hits the button, the code inflates the menu,

```
    alert.setTitle("Name"); //Set Alert dialog title here

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        final Button pencolor = new Button(this);       
        pencolor.setText("Select Pen Color");
        pencolor.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 30);
        registerForContextMenu(pencolor);

        ll.addView(input); ll.addView(pencolor);
        alert.setView(ll);
        alter.create();
        alert.show();
```

And here is the code for creating the context menu

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.color_menu, menu);
          menu.setHeaderTitle("Pick a color");


}
```

And here is the color_menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_red" android:title="Red" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_green" android:title="Green"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_blue" android:title="Blue"/>
</menu>
```

The alterdialog shows up, but when I click on the button nothing happens. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating your context menu, however you also have to define the action of every button. Add the following method to your activity (remember to change the action of every click, since this is just an example):

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if (item.getTitle().equals("Red")) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Action 1 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Green")) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Action 2 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else (item.getTitle().equals("Blue")) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Action 3 invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } 

   return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Rodolfo Perottoni. But that did not fix the problem. Another weird thing is that if I click and hold on the button the menu pops up but not when I click!

Comment: @user1512681 it should work. `onContextItemSelected` is the method used to define the actions of Context Menu clicks. Period. See if there is something wrong with you code. Also, i've updated the code to detect the button you've clicked by its title.